# Is there any way to transfer ETH in a contract function just like transferFrom for ERC20 tokens?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, transfer

I know that you can request an authorization and the transfer of ERC20 tokens from a contract user to another address with approval() and transferFrom().

But it here any equivalent to do the same for native ETH and a fixed amount of ETH ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can change your ether for WEth which is an ERC20 token that has the exact value of ether

Comment: Thanks, so no way to directly do it with the native ETH token ?

Comment: no, not without a smart contract

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear tbh but what I understood is, you are asking for a way to transfer ETH in solidity.

If that is the case then:

Yes You can easily make a funtion in your contract to send ether, specific amount of Eth by using `transfer` , `send` or `call`.
The call is the most recommended way to transfer Eth, as it is the more specific and secure way.
Check this out: https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/

Hope this helps, if I misunderstood your question then pls let me know :)

Comment: Hi, I had a hard time to search on goole about this, so yes I may not be clear. I want to know if there is a way to initiate a transfer from a contract user's wallet to another address just like it is possible with the transferFrom function on ERC20 tokens. I don't think it is possible, the native ETH transfer functions only allow to transfer from the contract to another address if I got it well.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you cannot move Native ETH from an EOA to another address using a smart contract.

You can however move ETH if it is sitting on a smart contract or if the ETH is in the form of Wrapped ETH (Weth) which is a ERC20 tokenized version of ETH.